# Is it possible to autocrop black borders of a video with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, script, automation, crop

I think it has a "blackness" video filter, which can determine if a picture sequence is black. Maybe it also has a filter to determine crop values automatically to remove black borders form edges of a video. Or maybe it is possible somehow to write a script using the "blackness" filter.

Answer (score 37):

Yes, it is possible.

First play your video to see if it is OK:

```
ffplay -i YourMovie.mp4 -vf "cropdetect=24:16:0"
```

The `cropdetect` filter values are:

```
cropdetect=limit:round:reset

limit = black threshold (default 24)
round = output resolution must be divisible to this
reset = after how many frames the detection process will start over
```

If it looks OK, crop it:

```
ffmpeg -i YourMovie.mp4 -vf "crop=640:256:0:36" YourCroppedMovie.mp4
```

---

Source and more info: René Calles blog [renevolution.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20190317205731/http://www.renevolution.com:80/ffmpeg/2013/05/23/understanding-ffmpeg-part-iii-cropping.html)

Comment: It might be helpful to put a start point (-ss 00:05:00) in when using cropdetect (before input -i) as some video will have a solid black screen when starting.

Comment: I would like to use this to crop `python` `matplotlib.animation` videos, which have a white border. Is it possible to alter the color of the border being detected?

Comment: Can you specify something else than black as border color? White for example?

Comment: This does not answer the question as you still need to do manual action

Comment: Hey @Cornelius can you please help me to find one command
- i want to crop video.mp4 from Square to Round using ffmpeg - not want to use overlay command for this

Comment: Your ffplay cropdetect command played my video but still had black on the right and bottom sides. Then I saw https://superuser.com/a/1035399/74576. And it occurs to me that maybe https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#cropdetect can't help at all for videos that have black sides of asymmetrical thicknesses. The documentation is not great.

Comment: A manual crop worked for my case: https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop `ffplay -i "myvid.mp4" -vf "crop=w=1104:h=830:x=0:y=0"`

Answer (score 19):

From: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17265381/ffmpeg-get-value-from-cropdetect

```
ffmpeg -i input -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1 | awk '/crop/ { print $NF }' | tail -1
```

Comment: ok, this will generate the "crop values" to use with ffmpeg in a simple and very clear way :), thx!

Comment: This fails miserably if there's a bit of black at the beginning of the video, such as in an  intro. This is solved by adding `-ss 5` before `-i`, to run `cropdetect` after skipping the first 5 seconds.

Comment: Save yourself a fork and get `awk` to only print the last matching field. `awk '/crop=/ {a=$NF} END{print a}'`

Comment: this line does NOTHING, where is the file name?

Comment: It's the "input"

Answer (score 5):

Putting the other two answers together into a script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#ffmpeg_zoom ver 20180128202453
I="$@";X=${I##*.};O=${I%.*}_zoomed.${X};f=$(which ffmpeg 2>/dev/null)
if [ ! "$f" ]||[ "$f" = '' ];then echo "Install ffmpeg";exit 1;fi
C=$($f -i "$I" -t 1 -vf cropdetect -f null - 2>&1|awk '/crop/{print $NF}'|tail -n1)
echo $f -i "$I" -vf "$C" "$O"; $f -i "$I" -vf "$C" "$O"
```

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/684747/zoom-video-using-ffmpeg-commands) has some relevant ffmpeg examples